# jvm options in tomcat

Tags: tomcat6

i need to add the following jvm options in tomcat

a] -Dcalltracerlib=calltracer5

b] -agentpath:C:\calltracer\jvmti\calltracer5.dll=traceFile-C:\calltracer\call.trace,filterFile-C:\calltracer\filters.txt,outputType-xml,usage-controlled

how can i configure tomcat

Answer (score 2):

From section 3.2 of this [Tomcat configuration page](http://www.chemaxon.com/jchem/doc/admin/tomcat.html):

> Windows running Tomcat 5.5 and later : Go to the "Apache Tomcat x.x" folder in the Start Menu. Start the "Configure Tomcat". 
>   Select the "Java" tab in the configuration dialog

It's been a while since I've run Tomcat myself, but that certainly sounds like a promising start... Alterantively, read the [Tomcat Windows Service HOWTO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html) which talks about using the `--JvmOptions` flag. Of course, that assumes you *are* running Tomcat as a Windows service. If you could give us more information we may be able to help more. If you're just running Tomcat from the command line, you may want to set the `CATALINA_OPTS` environment variable.

Comment: @pavan: I didn't downvote the question, but I *will* say that it doesn't show much sign of care or research. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints